# Is it safe to use static initialization on global handles in a C++CX application?

Tags: c++-cx

I'm working on a C++CX application where I have a global `Map^` of `String^` to `String^`, that I initialize and then never modify again.

In regular C++, the order in which global variables are initialized is unspecified. Because of that, I was wondering if I have to worry over the possibility that the COM runtime, on which handle types depend, hasn't been initialized by the time static initializers in C++CX are executed.